# change profile language

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture, uiculture

Web.config

```
<profile>
      <properties>
      <add name="Language"  />
      </properties>
</profile>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Profile.Language = "fr";
        string strCultur = Profile.Language;
        Page.Culture = strCultur;
        Page.UICulture = strCultur;
        lblLabel.Text = GetLocalResourceObject("lblLabelResource1").ToString();
    }
```

App_LocaleResource:

- Default.aspx.resx
- Default.aspx.fr.resx

This is my error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What do I wrong I want my text in french?

Comment: is there an object "null" not initialized in your code? If yes Would it be possible to specify which object == null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you can try this ?

or look more here

**win form c#  ->** [Change language of WinForm with resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896723/change-language-of-winform-with-resource)

```
using System.Globalization; 
using System.Threading;


//LanguageString sample
String languageString = "fr-FR";
//Apply new language
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(languageString);
Application.Run(new Form());
```

**asp.net c#** -> http://forums.asp.net/t/1244851.aspx/1

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```